# cannot override the height of form input in django

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-widget-tweaks

```html
<form role="form" action="" method="post" style="padding: 10%">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>LOG IN</label>
    {{ login_form.username|add_class:"form-control input_field"|attr:"placeholder:Username"}}<br>
    {{ login_form.password|add_class:"form-control input_field"|attr:"placeholder:Password" }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

```css
.input_field{
    height: 80px;
}
```

it dose not change the height of the form filed.

Comment: Because it is `height`, not `heigth`.

Comment: even correcting spelling does not work

Comment: !important tag worked to override